# Does the Seeking Spell Metamagic work on a weapon attack caused by a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic

The Seeking Spell Metamagic from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* reads:

> **Seeking Spell**
> If you make an attack roll for a spell and miss, you can spend 2 sorcery points to reroll the d20, and you must use the new roll.

My question is, what exactly counts as "an attack roll for a spell"? Obviously something like *Inflict Wounds* does, but does the weapon attack roll generated by a spell like *Booming Blade* count? What about a weapon attack roll for a weapon buffed by *Magic Weapon*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### If the spell effect says to make an attack roll, Seeking Spell works.

When a spell description instructs you to make an attack roll, the attack is part of the spell’s effect. The [rules for spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#CastingaSpell) in the *Player's Handbook* make this clear:

> Each spell description in Chapter 11 begins with a block of information, including the spell's name, level, school of magic, casting time, range, components, and duration. *The rest of a spell entry describes the spell's effect.*

So Seeking Spell will work on any spell where making an attack roll is explicitly part of the spell’s effect. *This includes booming blade*, since the attack rolls is part of the spell’s effect.

However, **this will not work** for *magic weapon* spell, since making attacks are not a part of the spell’s effect, the effect only modifies attacks, should you choose to make them. Indeed, [*magic weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-weapon) says:

> You touch a nonmagical weapon. Until the spell ends, that weapon becomes a magic weapon with a +1 bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls.

*Magic weapon* modified the properties of a weapon you touch - *this is the whole effect of the spell*. So Seeking Spell cannot be used with *magic weapon*.

---

It is important to note that Seeking Spell *does not require the attack made to be a "spell attack"*, just that the attack made is part of the spell's effect:

> If you make an attack roll for a spell and miss...

Comment: Can you comment on the interaction with _magic stone_, which defines an attack that can be made but doesn't directly tell you to make the attack?

Comment: Yeah, give me a minute.

Comment: @MarkWells That's a tough one. Based on my argument above, I think it probably works, but I also think it reasonable to rule that it doesn't.

Comment: @MarkWells A sorcerer with *magic stone* would be exceedingly rare, we're looking at multiclassing or someone taking the metamagic adept feat, so it's possible you'll never have to rule on that.